# PyDES with Bloomberg data

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, des, bloomberg

I am trying to decrypt DES encoded Bloomberg financial data with PyDES. The file ends in gz.enc, I am able to read the file to a binary, reload the binary back in to a variable (the variable has data)  and then use the following decryption on it.

```
k = pyDes.des(password, pyDes.ECB, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
released = k.decrypt(encrypted_data)
```

The problem is I get an empty string for 'released'. I unfortunately  cannot share the file nor the password due to privacy laws. I cannot use the bloomberg decryption as they do not support Ubuntu nor Mac.

Comment: How the encryption specifications? For example, why do you believe the file is DES encrypted? DES is a very unlikely choice because it has been deprecated for decades now. Triple-DES maybe, AES is most likely.

Comment: @JamesKPolk The password they gave us is an 8 bit key so it has to be DES

Comment: In case others find this while Googling, there are several scripts available to do this.  E.g. https://gist.github.com/ricklentz/7b80ae52fba1b9b06f5f213edf2002ba